# Magento 2.3.4. How does an AMP page get created?

Tags: magento2.3.2

I got this question as to how is an AMP page created because Google Search Console over and over again finds faults with the tags/attributes saying they are not allowed in an AMP page. All that I can edit is the content  of category pages and the product pages. Could you please point me in the right direction to some authentic documentation that I can rely on for better understanding of AMP?

Comment: Check this blog post if it helps! 1.https://magecom.net/how-to-create-accelerated-mobile-pages-in-magento-2/  2.https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/Accelerated-Mobile-Pages-AMP-for-Magento-2/ba-p/75729

Comment: The documentation is useful to some extent. thanks.